# Tomcat 8 SSL server.xml configuration not taken into account

Tags: ssl, certificate, tomcat

I've Tomcat 8.5.14 installed on a Debian server.

I could create a keystore and a certificate and all is running fine.

BUT :

- though a SSL Connector is configured in server.xml (see below) with a keystore supposed to be in /var/lib/tomcat8/conf/ (and it is there indeed), Tomcat only uses one that is in the root folder of Tomcat installation folder (/var/lib/tomcat8/)
- the name of the keystore must be ".keystore"

So, to make it work, WITHOUT CHANGING ANYTHING IN SERVER.XML, I had to :

- stop Tomcat service
- rename the old /var/lib/tomcat8/.keystore (date validity is over...)
- move /var/lib/tomcat8/conf/keystore.jks (a new certificate I've created) in /var/lib/tomcat8/
- rename keystore.jks to .keystore
- start Tomcat service

And it works, I can see the new certificate in browser.

So, my question is : what do I miss here ?

Here's server.xml Connector configuration :

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="8443" maxThreads="200"
                scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
                keystorefile="conf/keystore.jks" keystorePass="tomcat" keyAlias="tomcat"
                clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Comment: Is your `server.xml` in `/var/lib/tomcat8/`? Can you please try an absolute path? Also you have misspelled `keystoreFile` as `keystorefile`, maybe you need to change that?

Comment: I just can't believe it, my bad, I know it's case sensitive, I just can't read properly... It works now. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Configuration attributes are case sensitive. `keystorefile` will therefore be ignored. It needs to be `keystoreFile`.

Because your `keystorefile` setting is ignored Tomcat will use the default for `keystoreFile` which is `.keystore`. Because that is not an absolute path, it is resolved against `$CATALINA_BASE` - which in your case is `/var/lib/tomcat8` - hence the full path to the file Tomcat uses is `/var/lib/tomcat8/.keystore`.

Comment: I just can't believe it, my bad, I know it's case sensitive, I just can't read properly...

It works now.
Thank you so much !